# Search results not aligned with searchbar for UISearchController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I am trying to upgrade from a `UISearchDisplayController` to a `UISearchController`, but having a lot of strange problems with it. The current problem is that the search results do not align with the searchbar. In portrait mode, there is a small gap between the searchbar and the first search result:

[image]

(I have coloured the background of the results tableview yellow, to show its extend)

For landscape mode, the opposite is true: the searchbar overlaps the top of the results:

[image]

Strangly enough, if I then rotate the view with the results view still visible, it comes out perfectly.

My setup is a pretty standard approach, with the searchbar in the navigation bar, and the search results in a separate `UITableViewController`.
The code in my original view controller:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    SearchResults *searchResults = [[SearchResults alloc] init];
    searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:searchResults];
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = searchResults;

    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar;

    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = YES;
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
}
```

The `SearchResults` is a standard `UITableViewController` subclass, with no special formatting.

My suspicion was that it was due to incorrect contentInset of the tableview, so I printed those in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, which confirmed that suspicion.

How do I work around this apparent bug in `UISearchController` ?

Note: I have already tried to use any combination of `edgesForExtendedLayout`, `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets`, and `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` for the results tableview.

**EDIT:**
I have now logged a bug with Apple for this: https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6138130516148224

Answer (score 0):

I have found a work-around now that seems to work in all situations. I would still appreciate it if somebody can spot what I have done wrong in the original code.

For the work-around, in the SearchResults class, add the following:

```
- (void) viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    // Workaround for bug in UISearchController:
    CGFloat topInset = self.topLayoutGuide.length + (_searchController ? _searchController.searchBar.frame.size.height : 44);
    UIEdgeInsets insets = self.tableView.contentInset;
    if (topInset != insets.top) {
        // set the correct insets
        insets.top = topInset;
        self.tableView.contentInset = insets;
        // scroll to the top
        self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -topInset);
    }
}
```